# what's the difference between std::mem_fun and lambda in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

For this small code:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
void do_work(int id)
{
    cout<<this_thread::get_id()<<" "<<id<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    vector<thread> threads;
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        threads.push_back(thread(do_work, i));

    for_each(begin(threads), end(threads), [](thread & t){
        t.join();
    });
}
```

Option 1:

```
for_each(begin(threads), end(threads), [](thread & t){
                t.join();
            });
```

Option2:

```
for_each(begin(threads), end(threads), mem_fn(&thread::join));
```

Question:
1. which usage is better? 
2. what's the usage of `mem_fn`? could u  give a easy explantioan?

Comment: Which part of [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn) did you not understand? Since you already showed how to use `mem_fun`, what help do you need with usage? Better by what criteria?